# Adding a block in a specific part of the page

Tags: javascript

I have a website. Suppose there are 5 blocks with a height of 1000 pixels, how to perform a function using JS when I am on block 4 (in the specified case div class = 'one', changed c dispay = 'none' to 'flex')

```
<header></header>
<main>
    <div class="1"></div>
    <div class="2"></div>
    <div class="3 "></div>
    <div class="4 one"></div>
    <div class="5"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: you mean you want to execute a function when you scroll to a specific point in the website?

Comment: Do `document.getElementsByTagName("div").childNodes` to get the divs. Use a for loop to get to the 4th block. Then do `element.style.display = "flex";`.

Comment: I want to execute a function when you scroll to a specific point in the websit

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can get the element with `class="4 one"` with the following js code:

```js
var fouthElement = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0]
```

If you're trying to change the `display` style to `flex`, try this:

```js
var fouthElement = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0]
fourthElement.style.display = "flex"
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for clarifying the question. In that case using [a method mentioned in this article](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/), this might work to run function when the fourth element is in current view

```js
var isInViewport = function(elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        bounding.top >= 0 &&
        bounding.left >= 0 &&
        bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
};

var fouthElement = document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0]

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (isInViewport(fouthElement)) {
      alert("Element in view")
    }
})
```

Comment: I want to execute a function when you scroll to a specific point in the websit